# Strong Parameters for nested omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, strong-parameters

I have a Rails 4.0.13 app using Devise 3.5.10. My `User` model is `:omniauthable` using a *nested* `authentications` `has_many` relation, so the user can Omniauth by several providers:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => Authentication.auth_methods

  has_many :authentications, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :authentications
end
```

(I originally implemented this some time ago on Rails 3.2, so I don't recall the exact changes I had to make to make this work. I don't believe it's relevant, but can try to look it out if necessary).

This means that a User sign-up using Omniauth has parameters like:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{
  "authentications_attributes"=>
  {"0"=>{"provider"=>"open_id",
         "uid"=>"http://pretend.openid.example.com?id=12345",
         "nickname"=>"http://pretend.openid.example.com"}},
  "name"=>"Person1",
  "email"=>"Person1@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
  "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

I cannot figure out how to get strong parameters to permit this. My current attempt is `params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, authentications_attributes: {"0" => [:provider, :uid, :nickname]})`, but that still produces a log of `Unpermitted parameters: provider, uid, nickname`.

How can I permit these parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying nested parameters, the `XYZ_attributes` portion takes an array, not a hash.

In your case, try

`authentications_attributes: [:provider, :uid, :nickname]`

in

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, authentications_attributes: [:provider, :uid, :nickname])
```

Source: https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters

Comment: D'oh! I'd got so fixated on the "0" that I didn't think about how this would have to interact with `has_many`. Thanks, that's perfect.